# show activity after notification Android

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

I´m trying to open an activity after recieiving a PUSH notification.

I recieive the notification, but when i select it nothing happens!

The problem trace is:

```
W/InputMethodManagerService(771): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@438ae618 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@4319aab8
```

Here is my code

```
public class GCMIntentService extends IntentService {

private static final int NOTIF_ALERTA_ID = 1;

public GCMIntentService() {
    super("GCMIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if (!extras.isEmpty())
    {
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType))
        {
            mostrarNotification(extras.getString("message"));
        }
    }

    GCMBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

private void mostrarNotification(String msg)
{
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent notIntent = new Intent(this, OpenByNotificationActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, notIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning)
    .setContentTitle("Notificación AppMovil")
    .setContentText(msg)
    .setContentIntent(contIntent);

    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIF_ALERTA_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

and i´ve putted my Activity in the Manifest

```
<activity android:name="es.blabla.appmovil.activity.OpenByNotificationActivity" >
    </activity>
```

Where is the mistake???

Thanks to everyone!!

**Edit:**

**Fixed**
  adding `android:exported="true"` to my activity in the Manifest

Comment: try this: `PendingIntent contIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notIntent, 0);`

Comment: and second you need to pass `Context` when you create `Intent notIntent`

Comment: fixed!! adding android:exported="true" to my activity in the Manifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement this :

```
private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
String appname = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Notification notification;
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
new Intent(context, myactivity.class), 0);


 NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
 context);
 notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
 .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(appname).setWhen(0)
 .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(appname)
 .setContentText(message).build();

 notificationManager.notify(0 , notification);

  }
```

Comment: @SV you're right on way but one question user doing this into `Service` and you need to pass context in `new Intent(context, myactivity.class)` then how it's possible?

Comment: So basically, when you call GCMIntentService(), you can pass context parameter inside it and assign this.context there.

Comment: @SV that's what i am talk in about. +1 up for your _Awesome_ asnwer.

Comment: Doesn´t work... i´m calling the method with `generateNotification(getApplicationContext(), extras.getString("message"));`

Comment: Are you passing context inside GCMIntentService()?

Comment: fixed!! adding  `android:exported="true"` to my activity in the Manifest