# Android - Crash after click push notification message

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using cordova for my project. My app crash after I click push notification message. I got this error message in my log cat.

```
03-12 10:53:21.185: W/PluginManager(5548): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to PushPlugin.register blocked the main thread for 23ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
03-12 10:53:21.185: D/WebView(5548): loadUrlImpl: called
03-12 10:53:21.280: D/dalvikvm(5548): GC_CONCURRENT freed 581K, 12% free 12778K/14407K, paused 11ms+2ms, total 26ms
03-12 10:53:21.290: D/AndroidRuntime(5548): Shutting down VM
03-12 10:53:21.290: W/dalvikvm(5548): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fc72a0)
03-12 10:53:21.290: E/AndroidRuntime(5548): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 10:53:21.290: E/AndroidRuntime(5548): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@41d42d38 is not valid; is your activity running?
03-12 10:53:21.290: E/AndroidRuntime(5548): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:708)
03-12 10:53:21.290: E/AndroidRuntime(5548): at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:346)
03-12 10:53:21.290: E/AndroidRuntime(5548): at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
03-12 10:53:21.290: E/AndroidRuntime(5548): at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
```

Client side

GCMIntentService.java

```
package in.amolgupta.android.gcm;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

/**
 * {@link IntentService} responsible for handling GCM messages.
 */
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super("xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    }

    /**
     * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
     */
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                message, when);
        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
                SamplePushActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

        Log.d("GCM", "RECIEVED A MESSAGE");
        // Get the data from intent and send to notificaion bar
        generateNotification(arg0, arg1.getStringExtra("message"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

SamplePushActivity.java

```
package in.amolgupta.android.gcm;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

public class SamplePushActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView regNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        EditText regNO = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
        //uncomment below lines to unregister the device 
//      GCMRegistrar.unregister(this);
//      Log.d("info",
//              "unregistereddd....." + GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this));
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegistered(this)) {
            Log.d("info", GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this));
        }
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
        regNumber.setText(regId);
        regNO.setText(regId);
        if (regId.equals("")) {
            // replace this with the project ID
            GCMRegistrar.register(this, "xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            Log.d("info", GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this));
            regNumber.setText(regId);
            regNO.setText(regId);
        } else {
            Log.d("info", "already registered as" + regId);
        }

    }
}
```

Server side

Notify.java

```
package in.amolgupta.android.gcm.server;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.android.gcm.server.Message;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.MulticastResult;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender;

class Notify {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {

            Sender sender = new Sender(
                    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

            ArrayList<String> devicesList = new ArrayList<String>();
            devicesList.add("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
//          devicesList.add("yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy");
            devicesList.add("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz");
            // Use this line to send message without payload data
            // Message message = new Message.Builder().build();

            // use this line to send message with payload data
            Message message = new Message.Builder()
                    .collapseKey("1")
                    .timeToLive(3)
                    .delayWhileIdle(true)
                    .addData("message",
                            "this text will be seen in notification bar!!")
                    .build();

            // Use this code to send to a single device
            // Result result = sender
            // .send(message,
            // "APA91bGiRaramjyohc2lKjAgFGpzBwtEmI8tJC30O89C2b3IjP1CuMeU1h9LMjKhmWuZwcXZjy1eqC4cE0tWBNt61Kx_SuMF6awzIt8WNq_4AfwflaVPHQ0wYHG_UX3snjp_U-5kJkmysdRlN6T8xChB1n3DtIq98w",
            // 1);

            // Use this for multicast messages
            MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, devicesList, 1);
            sender.send(message, devicesList, 1);

            System.out.println(result.toString());
            if (result.getResults() != null) {
                int canonicalRegId = result.getCanonicalIds();
                if (canonicalRegId != 0) {
                }
            } else {
                int error = result.getFailure();
                System.out.println(error);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

You can refer to this site. I'm using her source code for my project.

https://github.com/hollyschinsky/PushNotificationSample30/

Comment: Are you passing the context? The issue is with your context.

Comment: what do you mean? context?

Comment: Context: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html ,  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android

Comment: Please post your code where you get crash.

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

[Show activity after notification Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296415/show-activity-after-notification-android/22296623#22296623)

Also, add **android:exported="true"** to your activity in your manifest file.

Hope this helps.