# App hangs on clicking the notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

Below is my code for showing a Notification, and after clicking it I redirect to another activity using the PendingIntent

But when I click on this notification my application hangs;

On checking my LogCat I see continues GC invoke logs

Please correct where am i going wrong:

```
private void showNotification(int notifyId, String alertMsg, PendingIntent intent) {
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(alertMsg))
                    .setSound(soundUri)
                    .setContentText(alertMsg);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(intent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(notifyId, mBuilder.build());
}
```

ALSO ABOVE CODE DOES PLAYS THE DEFAULT NOTIFICATION SOUND.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

HERE IS MY PendingIntent Code:

```
Intent contentIntent = new Intent(this, AccountDetailsActivity.class);
contentIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_TYPE, extras.getString("cat"));
contentIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_ACCOUNT_ID, extras.getString("rem"));
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                        NOTIFY_REQUEST_CODE, contentIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
showNotification(NOTIFICATION_TYPE_REMINDER, alertMsg, pendingIntent);
```

THANKS

Comment: Why are you using this Flag ? : `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

Comment: What should i use instead?, just got this from some online tutorial

Comment: This looks good to me. Not sure why it isn't working. Aren't you getting any exceptions in the logcat ?

Comment: No exception; after Clicking it i get a blank screen, and in logcat: GC is getting called frequently

Comment: and do you have any long processing stuff in the activity that is started on clicking the notification.

Comment: Did you tried your application on different devices?

Comment: Check this answer of mine : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22296623/1785412 and make changes as per your needs. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Found the bug, its in the activity that was been open after clicking. Thanks!

Comment: But is the sound not Playing?????